# Why doesn't the 'next button' work in a smaller screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to modify this code from site point, but I can't figure out why the 'next' button doesn't work in the screen size of 345px and below. What is the problem? I appreciate your help. Please see here for the complete code:
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/GmPjjL

```
<h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
<div class="quiz-container">
  <div id="quiz"></div>
</div>
<button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
<button id="next">Next Question</button>
<button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn't work' ? doesn't click / doesn't touch?

Comment: your slide overlap on button adjust your css

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Because label tag overlap the button tag

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your previous `label` tag is overlapping the `button` tag.

Change the position of the `button` and apply `z-index` to fix it.

```
button{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

[New Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/allanjebaraj/pen/EGRpbz)